# When i push the code to git every time asking me to sign in

Tags: git, devops

error: unknown option `timeout=3600'
usage: git credential-cache [options]

```
credential-cache is disabled in this build of Git
```

remote: invalid credentials
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Dhiman23/show/'

Please help me to find out the actual solution of the cause , i have tried using token method also but nothing is working i have configured my user.email and user.name both

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.